# How to execute unix command through odi and store the result in table

Tags: database, oracle11g, etl

I have to reconcile the  if data is loaded in table from flat file or not . I have to create a oracle data integrator package/interface/procedure to execute unix command to count number of rows in the csv files and store the result in a table then i have to query the loaded table and counfd number of rows there and store in the table and have to compare is counts are same or not,  Please assist me how to make package/interface/procedure to  execute unix command and store result in oracle table.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I would not solve this using Oracle Data Integrator, but simply use a Oracle package. It is possible to do so when the file which has been processed is on the same node and you can access it using utl_file and similar packages. You can open the CSV from PL/SQL, count the rows taking into the different line end styles available (CR/LF/CRLF) and then close the file again.
This does not give you the other features of running UNIX statements such as 'grep', but with utl_file you can open/read/write/close files and even with some effort list the files in a directory.
A free bonus is that the code becomes more portable to other platforms (Windows, where did VMS go?).

See below some samples taken from software we've developed at Invantive (feel free to use). You might want to use load_xxx_from_directory and then do a regexp_count as a simple solution. Or just count the CR/LF/CRLF yourself in a loop.

```
  --
  -- Load a file into a blob. Clob needed? Change blob to clob.
  --
  procedure load_blob_from_directory
  ( p_file      out nocopy blob
  , p_directory all_directories.directory_name%type
  , p_filename  varchar2
  )
  is
    l_read_buffer_size constant pls_integer := 32767;
    --
    l_fh               utl_file.file_type;
    l_read_buffer      raw(32767);
    l_bytes_read_sofar integer;
    l_bytes_read       integer;
  begin
    if p_file is null
    then
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(p_file, true);
    end if;
    l_fh := utl_file.fopen(p_directory, p_filename, 'rb');
    l_bytes_read_sofar := 0;
    begin
      while true
      loop
        utl_file.get_raw(l_fh, l_read_buffer, l_read_buffer_size);
        l_bytes_read := length(l_read_buffer) / 2;
        dbms_lob.write(p_file, l_bytes_read, l_bytes_read_sofar+1, l_read_buffer);
        l_bytes_read_sofar := l_bytes_read_sofar + l_bytes_read;
      end loop;
    exception
      when no_data_found
      then
        null;
    end;
    utl_file.fclose(l_fh);
  exception
    when others
    then
      --
      -- Close file if necessary.
      -- Ignore any errors.
      --
      begin
        if utl_file.is_open(l_fh)
        then
          utl_file.fclose(l_fh);
        end if;
      exception
        when others
        then
          null;
      end;
      --
      rollback;
      itgen_error_handler.add_to_inner_stack;
      raise;
  end;
```

Saving to a file:

```
  --
  -- Save the file in blob format to an Oracle directory.
  --
  procedure save_blob_to_directory
  ( p_file      blob
  , p_directory all_directories.directory_name%type
  , p_filename  varchar2
  )
  is
    l_piece_length constant pls_integer := 32767;
    --
    l_fh  utl_file.file_type;
  begin
    l_fh := utl_file.fopen(p_directory, p_filename, 'wb');
    for i in 0 .. trunc((dbms_lob.getlength( p_file ) - 1) / l_piece_length)
    loop
      utl_file.put_raw
      ( l_fh
      , dbms_lob.substr
        ( p_file
        , l_piece_length
        , i * l_piece_length + 1
        )
      );
    end loop;
    utl_file.fclose(l_fh);
  exception
    when others
    then
      --
      -- Close file if necessary.
      -- Ignore any errors.
      --
      begin
        if utl_file.is_open(l_fh)
        then
          utl_file.fclose(l_fh);
        end if;
      exception
        when others
        then
          null;
      end;
      --
      rollback;
      itgen_error_handler.add_to_inner_stack;
      raise;
  end;
```

Here is how to get size of a file:

```
function get_file_length 
( p_directory_name varchar2
, p_file_name      varchar2 
) 
return number 
is
  l_file_length     number;
  l_file_exists     boolean;
  l_file_block_size number; 
begin 
  utl_file.fgetattr 
  ( location    => p_directory_name 
  , filename    => p_file_name
  , fexists     => l_file_exists 
  , file_length => l_file_length 
  , block_size  => l_file_block_size 
  ); 
  return l_file_length; 
end;
```

Here is how to get contents of a directory:

```
function list_files 
( p_directory_name all_directories.directory_name%type
)
return itgen_tab_file 
pipelined 
as
  l_directory_path all_directories.directory_path%type;
  l_ns             varchar2(1024);
begin
  select dry.directory_path
  into   l_directory_path
  from   all_directories dry
  where  dry.directory_name = p_directory_name 
  ;
  sys.dbms_backup_restore.searchfiles(l_directory_path, l_ns);
  for r_files in 
  ( select fname_krbmsft file_name
    from   sys.itgen_x_krbmsft
  ) 
  loop
    pipe row
    ( itgen_rec_file
      ( p_directory_name
      , r_files.file_name
      , itgen_utilities.get_file_length (p_directory_name, r_files.file_name)
      )
    );
  end loop;
end;
```